# Oracle, Select rows from table where column value is in some range

Tags: sql, oracle, between

I have a Oracle table, where along with other columns there is an column named ERROR_CODE VARCHAR2. The values can be in the range 7000-7999 or 3000-3999. For eg if my ERROR_CODE column has the following values

```
ERROR_CODE

4567
7543
7001
6999
8000
```

How can i fetch all records which has the ERROR_CODE in the range say 7000-7999. Something like the Between clause. The output of my query should give

ERROR_CODE

```
7543
7001
```

Hope its clear. Thanks for any help

Comment: Just use the `between` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
from table 
where error_code between 7000 and 7999.
```

or

```
select *
from table
where error_code <=7999 and >=7000
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @CEvans. Though i was aware of the between clause but since the value was interger but the column data type was VARCHAR2 I wasn't sure whether the between clause would work. Thanks!!

Comment: between and the >< symbols will use the sort value.  So they can both by used with alpha characters, too.  In this case, though, since it looks like an integer it can be treated like one.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [BETWEEN](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/conditions011.htm) function of Oracle

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ERROR_CODE BETWEEN 7000 AND 7999
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Dennis de Jong. Though i was aware of the between clause but since the value was interger but the column data type was VARCHAR2 I wasn't sure whether the between clause would work. Thanks!!